# declaration of header and cpp files c++

Tags: c++, vector, parameters, header

So i'm trying to do a program where i input 3 values which are stored in a object and a fourth value which i generate from 2 of the other values and i store that object into a vector.
That problem is that i'm getting an error from the generatesignature function and i dont know what the problem is. I think it might have something to do how i declare the header file and the other cpp file since i havent done alot of programming involving these. So i'm asking to see if anyone can see anything wrong with what i have done so far.
The errors i'm getting are LNK1120 1 unresolved externals and the second one is LNK2019 unresolved external symbol

Project.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "constants.h"
using namespace std;
      int main()
            {
                    vector<Data> dataVector;
                    struct Data newdata;
                    newdata.fname = "testfname";
                    newdata.lname = "testlname";
                    //add signature
                    newdata.signature = generateSignature("testfname","testlname",dataVector);
                    newdata.height = 1.85;
                    dataVector.push_back(newdata);
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataVector.size();i++) {
                        cout << dataVector.at(i).fname << " " << dataVector.at(i).lname + " " + dataVector.at(i).signature << " " << dataVector.at(i).height << endl;
                    }
            }
```

constants.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct Data {
    string fname;
    string lname;
    string signature;
    double height;
};
string generateSignature(string fname, string lname, vector<Data>& data);

#endif
```

constants.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "constants.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;
string generateSignature(string fname, string lname, vector<Data>& data) {
    string signature+=fname;
    signature+="test123";

    //some random code for the vector
    return signature;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Most probably a duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), but since you don't tell us what the error actually is :-P ...

Comment: My bad!, first error is: LLNK1120 1 unresolved externals   and the second one is LNK2019 unresolved external symbol

Answer (score 0):

You can't use += in declaration. Just change `string signature+=fname;` to `string signature=fname;`